# Ansible role does not read templates in playbook dir or other role's templates dir

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am new to Ansible and Jinja2. Any help would be appreciated!

- Ansible version: 2.4.1
- Execution environment: Windows bash
- Test sample: https://bitbucket.org/tsz662/jinja-test

#### Problem

Ansible does not recognize Jinja templates located in another role when the including role is specified by absolute path.

**Directory structure**

```
 .
    ├── files
    │   └── test_2.yml
    ├── hosts
    ├── roles
    │   ├── common_role
    │   │   ├── tasks
    │   │   │   └── main.yml
    │   │   ├── templates
    │   │   │   └── common.j2
    │   │   └── vars
    │   │       └── main.yml
    │   └── role_A
    │       ├── tasks
    │       │   └── main.yml
    │       └── templates
    │           ├── mytemplate_2.j2
    │           └── mytemplate.j2
    └── site.yml
```

**site.yml**

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - common_role
    - role_A
```

**role_A/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: test relative path
  template:
    src: mytemplate.j2
    dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/files/test_1.yml"

- name: test absolute path
  template:
    src: mytemplate_2.j2
    dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/files/test_2.yml"
```

**role_A/templates/mytemplate.j2**

```
{% include 'roles/common_role/templates/common.j2' %}
msg: I am mytemplate.j2 and including {{common_templates}}.
```

**role_A/templates/mytemplate_2.j2**

```
{% include playbook_dir + 'roles/common_role/templates/common.j2' %}
msg: I am mytemplate_2.j2 and including {{common_templates}}.
```

#### Execution result

```
tsz@mylaptop:/mnt/c/Users/tsz/jinja-test$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml

PLAY [all] **************************************************************

TASK [role_A : test relative path] ***************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role_A : test absolute path] ***************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "TemplateNotFound: /mnt/c/Users/tsz/jinja-test/roles/common_role/templates/common.j2"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/mnt/c/Users/tsz/jinja-test/site.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

#### File permissions

```
tsz@mylaptop:/mnt/c/Users/tsz/jinja-test$ ls -al roles/common_role/templates
total 13
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 15:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 16:04 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Nov 10 15:57 common.j2

tsz@mylaptop:/mnt/c/Users/tsz/jinja-test$ ls -al roles/role_A/templates
total 129
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 16:00 .
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 15:59 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  133 Nov 10 16:40 mytemplate_2.j2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  115 Nov 10 16:11 mytemplate.j2
```

Comment: Will it work with a relative path? Can you symlink the file to the calling role? Show us the calling task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you pointed out, it works with relative paths but not with absolute paths. As for the simlink, sorry, the real project is in our team private repo.

Comment: Check the permissions along each directory of /playbook/roles/common_role/templates/common.j2 for the executing user. Is this a consistent and repeatable series of those two errors? Do they flip-flop, or is the change persistent?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply! Problem #2 was my stupid mistake of not loading common_role first, so I removed it from my question.

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7106) states that you can't include anything outside of your roles. I wonder if that is what's hanging you up? Your full path includes dirs that are explicitly above the roles, even if the endpoints are not. Has ANYONE managed to use full paths for templates includes? ( still testing )

Answer (score 2):

I think this isn't going to work with the current version of jinja.
My *suspicion* is that you can't use literal paths because they include directories outside the role space.
c.f. [this thread](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7106).

Someone please prove me wrong. I'm out of time to test it, but it could easily be an artifact of the odd environment setup I have to use.

The template:

```
$: cat roles/example/templates/tst
stuff etc
{% include '/full/path/redacted/roles/example/templates/other' %}
```

The included template exists:

```
$ ls -l /full/path/redacted/roles/example/templates/other
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 180 Nov 10 10:06 /full/path/redacted/roles/example/templates/other
```

The output:

```
TemplateNotFound: /full/path/redacted/roles/example/templates/other
```

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Your replies supported my suspicion that we cannot use literal paths for templates right now, and I really thank you for your effort and time.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more actual help. Was a good learning experience for me though. Cheers.